# Grails download link

Tags: file, url, grails, svg, download

I have a link thats used to download files from my server. The link passes svg (xml) as a paramater. THe server creates a jpeg using this xml and passes it back to the view to initiae a download.

The problem is that in IE only a portion of the xml is being passed due to the limit on url size. It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome (where there must be bigger url limits).

The xml being passed comes from javascript so I need to update the link on the fly on the client side : 
html :

```
<g:link class="button" action="testImage" id="my-link"><input type="button" value="PDF" class="invisible"/></g:link>
```

JS:

```
 svgXML = "<svg ......</svg>" //can get very long
 document.location.href= '${createLink(controller: 'imageCreater' , action:'downloadJPEG')}?svg='+svgXML;
```

Is there a way around this approach? I cant use ajax as it requires a plugin to initiate the download after it gets passed to the view. Due to requirements I cant use this plugin. I've read somewhere that POST requests don't have a limit on paramater size. Is there a way to change my link to do a POST rather then a GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across the same problem. I couldn't find a straight forward fix for my problem using a grails link. I came across the [jQuery-File-Download](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-File-Download) plugin and its working perfectly